# How to bypass lockscreen on Android Marshmallow?

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, data-recovery, locked-out

After updating to Android Marshmallow, my PIN is no longer being accepted. I haven't forgotten the PIN, it's a 4 digit I have been using for 8 months, nobody else has physical access to my phone, so I am pretty sure it has not been changed by someone.

USB Debugging is disabled, no root, bootloader is locked, Full Disk Encryption is disabled. Please do not suggest a factory reset. Android Device Manager doesn't work either.

What can I do? Is there anyway to get the data off the device, aside from JTAG or sending it to some data recovery company who can remove the Memory Chip and interface with it directly and copy the data that way? Is there any way to bypass the lockscreen?

Comment: No direct answer, but a pointer: Have you already checked with our [locked-out tag-wiki](/tags/locked-out/info) and followed its links? There's one answer summing up a lot of ways concerning pattern lock.